# Can someone explain the correlation layer in FlowNet in a simple way?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, opticalflow

I am currently reading the paper "FlowNet: Learning Optical Flow with Convolutional Networks" and having trouble understanding the correlation layer.

I can't seem to find any explanation on google, so I thought I should ask her:

1. When the paper talks about comparing each patch from f_1 to each patch from f_2, where f_1 and f_2 are feature maps of dimension w*h*c, what do they mean by patch? Are we talking about a patch of features from a feature map or a patch of pixels from one of the original images?
2. what is x_1 and x_2? Are they a feature pixel (1*1*c) in the feature maps? are they coordinate values?
3. What does f_1(x_1 + o) mean exactly?

Many thanks!

Comment: I just realized my answer didn't answer some of your questions.
1. They definitely mean patch of features from a feature map.
2. x_1 and x_2 are center locations (i.e. value (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) in the feature maps with which neighborhoods are used as patches.
3. f_1(x_1+o) is the tensor of shape C (for C channels) obtained from the feature map f_1 at location x_1 + (u, v) for u in [-k, k], and v in [-k , k], o is basically an offset equal to (u,v).

Answer (score 0):

From feature map-2 the patch of 21x21x256 is extracted only once and then each 1x1x256 kernel from feature map-1 is convolved with this (21x21x256) patch.

**More Explanation:**
 Each (1x1x256) kernel from feature map-1 is convolved with only  *pixel-1* of patch (21x21x256) to get one feature map and then all (1x1x256) kernels of feature map-1 are again convolved with *pixel-2* of (21x21x256) patch to get second feature map 
This process is continued for all pixels of (21x21x256) patch till we get 441 feature maps which is equal to number of pixels in extarcted feature map.[please look at this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d2iH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, suppose you have two feature maps (ignoring batches for the moment):

f_1 of shape (w, h, c),

f_2 of shape (w, h, c)

Then there are two stride values s_1 and s_2. The first stride s_1 is applied to f_1 in the sense that we only consider feature map patches x_i of f_1 at strided patch centers. For instance if the stride was 5 (in both the height and width direction), we would consider patches at locations:

(0,0), (0,5), ..., (0, w)

(5,0), (5,5), ..., (5, w)

...

(h,0), (h, 5), ..., (h, w)

** (supposing the width/height are divisible by 5 for simplicity, otherwise you have to do some padding arithmetic)

For a given patch center x_i, the patch centers , call them {y_i}, of f_2 considered in the correlation operation around x_i are only those that are within a neighborhood of size D := 2d+1, and those are strided as well with stride value s_2. There will be D^2 of these, according to the authors. (This part is not well described in my opinion as there are many ways of interpreting what the stride value s_2 means. If s_2 = 1, then there will be D^2 patches {y_i} of f_2 to consider, but if it is larger, there should be less, and hence the final tensor shape will not necessarily be D^2 in the last axis.)

The correlation operation itself is a simple sum of dot products, where the dot products are taken with vectors of shape (1, c) * (1, c), of which there will be K^2 of these summed, where K=2k+1 (an odd-sized filter for some positive integer k).

Answer (score -1):

1. patch of features from feature map
2. feature pixel (1*1*c) in the feature maps
3. feature pixel located in distance o from x1

correlation layer in flownet computes patches from feature maps(first feature map and second feature map).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiGTH.png)

to calculate correlation between feature pixel x1 and feature pixel x2, correlation layer computes dot product between windows(size (2k+1,2k+1)) that centered x1 and x2. so they just do dot product between elements in windows and add them up.